# Text at the top of Android Tab host layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

I followed [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) example and got it worked.

Now I want to show a 'Welcome!!!' text just above the tabs in a [Tabhost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html) layout just like one show in figure

[image]

Here is my current layout file. But it does not show the Welcome message.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:padding="5dp">
            <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/cc_welcome" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Welcome"
                android:gravity="top" android:padding="50dp" android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingTop="50dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have edited the xml file. Have a try with this :

**Updated**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/welcome"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/cc_welcome" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Welcome"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_below="@id/welcome"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@android:id/tabs"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I have updated the code. Can you please try now.

You will get a better idea about the Linear and Relative layout [here](http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-layouts-part-one-linear-and-relative-layouts/)